# How to create a unique random username for django?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I want visitors of my page to be able to create entries without registering first. When they register later I want everything they have created within that session to belong to their user account.

To achieve that I just want to create blank users with random usernames when entries from non users are made.

What is the most elegant way to create a unique username randomly avoiding any collision?

Should I just make a while loop that generates usernames and tries to save them to the db with a break upon success or is there a better way?

Most scripts I've seen just create a random string, but that has the danger of a collision. Is there any Django function that creates random usernames based on which usernames are already taken?

Comment: What is the merit in having them random vs. incremental? Incremental username will assure you with zero collision and remain unqiue.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just do anonymous<monotonicallyincreasingid>?

Comment: If user can register later with any username then the "incremental" solution will not work.

Comment: Because then I still have to check whether someone just choose anonymous-45 by chance or I need a filter that forbids users to create that username. And it doesn't feel good to me that attackers might guess usernames. So random plus check in a loop just seems more secure and lightweight.

Comment: @catavaran if will work. say incremental func returned 5, then we concatenate username+5, nobody can be issued username5 thereafter.

Comment: @taesu and then some troll will register the "username6"...

Comment: then that guy will be name username6 + 6

Comment: You can embed the current date/time into the username to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Adding something to a username even if it is chosen by the user doesn't seem like a very good solution. First the usernames would be cluttered and users might have problems logging in. Second it's doubling information in the database as every user already has a unique id that increments. So what are your arguments for going this way? Also something like username=test6 with uid=6  and username=test and uid=66 might cause trouble that is a nightmare to debug.

Comment: There, you're contradicting yourself. `every user already has a unique id that increments` why not use that instead of randomized user name that might have collision?

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. Django provides a unique ID for every user and it requires a unique username to create a user. Now writing that ID (or any other incremental bit) to the username field as some sort of salt sounds like duplicated information.

Comment: all I am saying is that `a unique ID for every user ` that is already created can be used as their username. It never has collision, will add absolutely no overhead what so ever.

Comment: I get that, but it completely destroys the possibility for the users to choose a name they can identify with as an ID is always added to it. Also if you follow my example with username:test6+id:6 and username:test+id:66 you might agree that there are additional security caveats. So I believe this way is very messy.

Comment: You can have the username blank until they create their user account and use the unique id as username. I was just questioning the need for the existence of randomly generated username that might have collision.

Comment: @taesu username is unique so it can't be blank. This is the requirement of the django auth app.

Comment: Ah now I get what you mean. Sorry maybe that was due to me not being a native speaker. You are saying I should use the unique id as the string that goes into the username field if it's a generated user. Does Django prevent users from signing up with number only usernames? Because if not somebody might cause a collision by choosing "123" as a username and then waiting for enough generated users to show up.

Comment: That is a valid point, you just made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, django doesn't have such function.  So you have to check for the existence of the generated username in the loop.

Comment: Is this True even at the end of 2020?

Comment: Yes. Even at the end of 2020 you have to check the generated username for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I created a mixin that creates a random username based on firstname, lastname and makes sure this username doesnt already exist in db User model:

**random_username_mixin.py**

```
import random
import string

from core.models import CustomUser


class RandomUsernameMixin:
    """
    using firstname & lastname
    create a random username (all lower case)
    that doesnt already exist in db
    """
    num_of_random_letters = 3
    num_of_random_numbers = 2
    user_model = CustomUser

    def get_username(self, firstname=None, lastname=None):
        username = ''
        if firstname and lastname \
                and firstname != '' and lastname != '':
            username = firstname[0] + lastname[0]

        while True:
            random_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
            random_numbers = string.digits
            username += self.get_random_char(
                random_letters, self.num_of_random_letters
            )
            username += self.get_random_char(
                random_numbers, self.num_of_random_numbers
            )
            if self.username_exist_in_db(username) is False:
                return username

    def username_exist_in_db(self, username):
        """
        :return: True if username already exist in db
            else False
        """
        q = self.user_model.objects.filter(username=username)
        return q.exists()

    def get_random_char(self, ip_str, n):
        return (''.join(
            random.choice(ip_str)
            for i in range(n)
        ))
```

Following is the testing code. It tests the above code:

**test_random_username_mixin.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

from miscellaneous.mixins.random_username_mixin import RandomUsernameMixin


class TestRandomUsernameMixin(RandomUsernameMixin,
                              TestCase):

    def test_username_with_fn_ln(self):
        fn = 'aseem'
        ln = 'hegshetye'
        username = self.get_username(
            firstname=fn, lastname=ln
        )
        len_of_initials = 2
        len_of_username = self.num_of_random_numbers + \
                          self.num_of_random_letters + \
                          len_of_initials
        self.assertEqual(len(username), len_of_username)
        print(username)

    def test_username_without_fn_ln(self):
        username = self.get_username()
        len_of_initials = 0
        len_of_username = self.num_of_random_numbers + \
                          self.num_of_random_letters + \
                          len_of_initials
        self.assertEqual(len(username), len_of_username)
        print(username)
```